# Python - Extract yyyyMMddhhmmss from file using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get the date (format is yyyymmddhhmmss) from a string using Regex but I cannot find the pattern to use.

I am trying with the code below:

```
import re
string = "date file /20190529050003/folder "
regex = re.compile(r'\b\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}\s\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}\b')
result = regex.findall(string)[0],
print(result)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
result = regex.findall(string)[0],
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I use regex to return "20190529050003" from the string that I have on my script?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a ```\s``` in your expression that's messing it up

Comment: regex101.com is a great resource for debugging regexes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If our date is right after the slash, we can simply use this expression:

```
.+\/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}).+
```

Then, if necessary, and we wish to add more boundaries, we can surely do so, such as:

```
.+\/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}).+
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vxAnFZ/1/)

or:

```
^.+\/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\/.+$
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/AeMcNg/1)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r".+\/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}).+"

test_str = "date file /20190529050003/folder "

subst = "\\1-\\2-\\3"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

---

If we might want to get all the numbers, then we could use another expression:

```
.+\/(\d+)\/.+
```

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r".+\/(\d+)\/.+"

test_str = "date file /20190529050003/folder "

subst = "\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ywyJ4Z/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your regex pattern is off, because there is no space in the target timestamp.  Here is one simple way to perform your search:

```
string = "date file /20190529050003/folder "
matches = re.findall(r'\b\d{14}\b', string)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['20190529050003']
```

We could try to make the pattern more targeted, and e.g. only allow valid values for the hours, minutes, etc. fields.  But, that would be a lot more work, and if you don't expect to see any 14 digit numbers in your text which are *not* timestamps, then I suggest eschewing making the pattern more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: How is this different than the OP's code? According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.findall) the two should have similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Got rid of `\s` from the expression.

```
string = "date file /20190529050003/folder "
regex = re.compile(r'\b\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}\b')
result = regex.findall(string)[0]
'20190529050003'
```

Comment: There is no point at all in having so many separate `\d{x}` groups.  Just use `\d{14}`.

Comment: Agreed, but I wanted to explain why the original code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest breaking the line that causes an error into two lines:

```
matches = regex.findall(string)
result = matches[0]
```

Now you can inpsect `matches` to see what it contains.

Comment: The regex pattern has a problem, which your answer fails to mention.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are correct. I was just pointing the OP in the direction of how to diagnose the problem.